# Dynamic binding update image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an image list(ListBox) stacked with titles and description. The Image is not downloaded yet but title and description would show first. When the image is downloaded, how can I tell to update the image?

Partial xaml:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Column="0" Name="DCIM" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Title}" Name="Title" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Desc}" Name="count" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your item class:

```
public class MyDataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ImageSource image;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    // do the same for Title and Desc

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

When the `Image` property is assigned to, a property change notification is raised which updates the binding.

Answer (score 0):

When the image is downloaded call  `NotifyProperyChanged("Image")` to update `Source="{Binding Image}"`